# "Unsupported non-primitive compare" on Chrome profiler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I have a bottleneck in my application,

Chrome is telling the problem is `Unsupported non-primitive compare`, I'm not sure I understand what It means.

Here's the exact code for the problem (see line 6)

```
for (var key in this.gdata) {
  var rows = this.gdata[key];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) first[key] = rows[i];
    if (rows[i].date > dt) {
      curr[key] = i > 0 && rows[i - 1]; //   <----  problem is here
      next[key] = rows[i];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot just in case:

[image]

Here we can see the bottleneck more in details:

[image]

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: what is the type of `rows[i - 1]`?

Comment: Maybe V8 is having a hard time trying to convert the `rows[i - 1]` object to a primitive type because of the complexity of it. Overriding the `valueOf` method on the object's prototype might help with this.

Comment: @loa_in_ it's an object

Answer (score 0):

Crankshaft cannot optimize that because it has to convert `rows[i-1]` to a boolean and it does not know how to do so without deoptimizing. Maybe this would work better?

`curr[key] = i > 0 ? rows[i-1] : false;`

Comment: `&&` does not return only `true` and `false`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Chrome does not always time the rows where it finds this particular problem, nor does it signal the most time-spending row.
In my case, this error has always happened for time comparisons.

If you change rows[i].date > dt to rows[i].date.getTime() > dt.getTime() does the warning go away?